# How can I determine what program/process is calling for sjjgtggx.dll?

Tags: windows-vista

I receive this error message during boot: Error loading C:\users\owner\AppData\Local\Mozilla\sjjgtggx.dll The specified module could not be found.
How do I determine what program/process is calling for this dll?

Comment: this was malware but the run keys are still present.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/bb896653) from [SysInternals](http://www.sysinternals.com/), now a part of [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/). Run it as admin, then go to Find -> Find Handle or DLL. It will highlight any process that includes a handle to that DLL.

Since the module could not be found, it may not appear in Process Explorer, so then try [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), also from [SysInternals](http://www.sysinternals.com/). Start a capture, and after a while, search for your DLL. You should be able to identify the process attempting to load it.

Comment: If I am not mistaken neither Process Explorer nor Process Monitor works during boot.

Answer (score 0):

Sysinternals will show only a dll, which is used by something! But your problem is, that this all isn't simply found.

But luckily I have the answer. The dll can't be found in AppData/Mozilla. If not firefox/thunderbird, but some other software try to load here dlls, then there are some very, very bad in your system and at first I suggest a full virus clean there.

If it is some software from the Firefox, that can you test if you rename this folder, reboot and tests if the error message is coming or not. If don't, then the problem is that your Mozilla/AppData is broken, and you can delete it (only after saved any important files there, especially some bookmarks.html or like).

If the error message is further coming, and the virus clean didn't found anything, then it is a mystic error. At first I searched the full registry for this sjggtggx.dll.